# PHP and Mysqli with Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have the below function that i want it to retrieve matching records from MySQL Database:

```
public function GetUserData($conn){
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL GetUserData(?)") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error($conn));
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
        $stmt->execute() or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error($conn));
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            print_r($row);
        }
        exit;
    }
```

GetUserData is a stored procedure as below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetUserData`(IN `StoredUsername` VARCHAR(255))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
select firstname from users where username=StoredUsername;
END
```

My problem, is that the `print_r($row)` only prints "1"
In case the matching rows is two, it prints "11"

I can't seem to figure out what am i using/doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- mysqli_stmt_fetch() is doing not what you think
- Username should be passed via parameters
- While connection should be a class variable
- After getting result, you have to move over additional result returned by procedure, in order to be able to run other queries.

  ```
  public function GetUserData($username){
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("CALL GetUserData(?)");
      $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
      $stmt->execute();
      $data = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all();
      $this->conn->next_result(); 
      return $data;
  }
  ```

Also, instead of checking result of every database command manually, tell mysqli to throw errors by itself, automatically. Add this line before mysqli_connect and forget all these ugly `or die` forever:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it.
On a side note, i can access the result by index and not by field name, for ex, foreach($data as $row) echo $row['username'] is invalid, $row[0] works.
How can fetch the results by field name like the usual mysql_fetch_assoc?